# linux: job submitted to sge stuck in 'dt' state

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, qsub

I tried adding a job to sqe by qsub. But it seems to be stuck. The state is shown as 'dt'. What could be wrong? I cannot add run any more jobs due to this. How can I remove the job from queue?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You'll need to provide more details about what the problem is, and what you have tired to fix the problem. Most likely you will need to run `qdel foo` but that could vary depending on what version of qsub you are running.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a grid engine status.  If that is the case the 'd' means the job is in the process of being deleted while the 't' means the job is being transfered to the node where it is supposed to run.  This combination usually occurs only if the node crashed while the job was being transfered to it.

You should be able to delete it with `qdel -f JOBID` if you are the administrator or the cluster is appropriately configured.  If not ask your sysadmin/support to do it for you.